# Rotating Linked List to the Left Once without using return

Tags: python-3.x

in my computer science class, I have to (among other things) rotate a sentineled doubly-linked array to the left once using a function without returning.
Essentially that function under class Linked_List, what I have is this:

```
def rotate_left(self):
    Linked_List[1:] + Linked_List[:1]
```

While running my test cases currently after appending, etc my array looks as follows:

```
[5,10,15,20]
```

then I use "a" (which is my test case variable) and then implement

```
a.rotate_left()

print(a)
```

and it will not run. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How about you actually call your method, i.e. `a.rotate_left()` (notice the parenthesis at the end). Also, shouldn't your method modify the list or return a value as well - as it stands your method is just summing them up.

Comment: @zwer "es, looks like that was the problem! It means I was not even running it, an amateur mistake. That being said: "rotate_left(self) Without constructing any new node objects and
without returning anything, rotate the list left so that each node moves
one position earlier than it was and the original head becomes the new
tail. The length of the list should not change. If the list is empty, this
method has no effect." However, I can not get it to work properly. Is there any way you can help me?

Comment: Do it by reconnecting the links between nodes.